# ROS2 Iron System Setup vcs

Tags: ros2

I'm trying to complete the 'Build ROS2' in the system setup for ROS2 Iron (MacOS). When I try to run the following code: `vcs import --input https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/iron/ros2.repos src`

I get this error:

```
vcs: unrecognized option `--input'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Sorry, I am not sure about MacOS but it works well on Ubuntu. I tested just now with `vcs version 0.3.0` and found it working well. `$ vcs --version` shows `vcs 0.3.0`

Comment: Please provide how `vcstool` is setup/installed (AFAIK, installer of `vcstool` is NOT provided by maintenance team, so I assume you did it manually). I confirmed v0.3.0 has the option in question.

Comment: @IsaacS I was able to get the issue resolved, I needed to install Java in order to install vcstool.

Comment: @victrola10 Glad you resolved it. Can you post that as an answer instead of a comment? That way other people in the future can more easily find how the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Needed to install Java in order to install vcstool.

Comment: This seems highly unrelated. vcstool is written in Python. I don't see a single reason why would it care about Java.